# Issues with Rails 6 test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby 2.7 and Rails version 6.0.2.1
When I try to test my model I get this message

```
Error:
OfferTest#test_valid_offer:
DRb::DRbRemoteError: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "views" does not exist
LINE 8:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"views"'::regclass
                            ^
 (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

rails test test/models/offer_test.rb:4
```

This is my schema file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_01_20_105655) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "offers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "city"
    t.string "area"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "contact_person"
    t.string "contact_person_phone"
    t.string "denomination"
    t.string "category"
    t.string "typology"
    t.integer "guests"
    t.integer "rooms"
    t.boolean "lift"
    t.decimal "expense"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "requests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "address"
    t.decimal "budget"
    t.date "date_of_request"
    t.string "document_id"
    t.string "phone"
    t.string "residential_address"
    t.date "date_of_birth"
    t.string "notes"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "last_name", null: false
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Ad of now I have 3 tables. I am testing the Offer model but I get this strange behaviour.
This is my test model code

```
require 'test_helper'

class OfferTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "valid offer" do
    offer = Offer.new(city: "Rome", area: "Zona Sud", address: "Via Roma")
  end
end
```

I've already run rails db:test:prepare but I cannot fix this issue.

Comment: can you provide your `schema.rb` with views table?

Comment: I've provided the schema

Comment: Can you please also post your `test/models/offer_test.rb` code?

Comment: I've provided the model test code

Comment: Please show your `app/models/offer.rb` model code.

Comment: Strange you only show us local database, but you get a `Drb::DrbRemoteError` suggesting that the `views` association is not in your local db (remote?). Does the `Offer` class contain a link to something remote, or is there a `views` definition in the class?

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is that some gem is injecting behaviour into your models.

Something is expecting a table "views". The name `views` hints at either a gem using database `views` to virtualize tables, or some gem that works in the domain with `views`: for example a gem for statistics (An order has been viewed 21 times: has 21 views).

I'd suggest removing all gems from your gemfile and re-including them one by one. This will tell you what gem is injecting this behaviour: knowing what your dependencies do is an important part of building an app, IMO.

If it is a gem, that gem most probably has some migrations that you need to install and run:

```sh
bundle exec rake railties:install:migrations
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Could it be Devise?

Comment: I've tried to run those commands but still getting the same issue..

Comment: Devise is known for injecting bucketloads of cruft into controllers, models and so on, but not, AFAIK, "views". 

In any case: did cleaning out your gemfile and starting with a lean and vanilla "rails" show anything interesting WRT a views table being referenced?